# MacBook is laggy when switching apps

Tags: mac, memory, performance, cpu-usage, virtual-memory

On my MacBook I experience lags when switching apps or when the debugger hits an exception/breakpoint and brings my IDE to the top.

The CPU usage is quite low, as you can see in the following image. Usually it is even lower, but currently the mds process is running (I think it is the one for spotlight indexing):

[image: CPU usage]

The memory pressure also looks good and it says that only 12.24 of 16GB are in use.

[image: Memory usage]

However, if I run top on the command line I get this output:

[image: Top 1]

It says that only 124MB are unused (this number goes also down to a few MB from time to time).

What also happens very frequently are the swapins and outs, as you can see in the next screenshot. Mostly it happens if I switch apps or tabs in Safari. It ranges from a few hundred to ~30,000 (for both, ins and outs). If I don't do anything, I consistently have around 200 swapins.

[image: Top 2]

Is this an indicator that I should get a new MacBook with more RAM?

Current specs:

[image]

Comment: 12.24 GB used by programs + 3.75 GB ”used“ by cache = 15.99 GB. Everything normal.

Comment: Everything normal, but yeah, you've got 'swap lag' every time you switch apps. More RAM is the fix, assuming you're already running on an SSD with plenty of space left.

Comment: Can you tell me what spec/model macbook you have, including HDD/SSD?

Comment: @DanielB Thanks! But why is there so much swap activity?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I have attached the specs to my posting. I am running an SSD with more then 500GB of free space.

Comment: can you create a new user then login and check the same things? You may have something in your login profile which is causing this.

Comment: I have reinstalled MacOS from scratch a few days ago (including my IDEs, of course). If I only start one app directly after rebooting, everything runs smoothly. Then there are also no swapping activities. After starting more apps, my Mac starts to swap things and it becomes more laggy.

Comment: what apps are you opening and how many instances of each? Remember that chrome is incredibly wasteful with ram and each new tab is a new instance of chrome.